# Abel-Jacobi map (not) holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

It is well known (Miranda's Algebraic Curves and Riemann surfaces, p. 266) that if $X$ is a Riemann surface of genus one, then the Abel-Jacobi map, that is defined (locally) as $$J(p)=\int_{p_0}^p \omega,$$ where $p_0$ is a fixed basepoint on $X$, and $\omega$ is a holomorphic 1-form on $X$, is a holomorphic function (of $p$). This fact is used to show that Riemann surfaces of genus 1 and complex 1-tori are the same thing. If the genus of $X$ is $g\geq 2$, then we fix a basis $\omega_1, \ldots. \omega_g$ of the holomorphic 1-forms on $X$, and we define the Abel-Jacobi map as $$J(p)=\Big(\int_{p_0}^p \omega_1, \ldots, \int_{p_0}^p \omega_g\Big).$$ Now, this map cannot be holomorphic, because it would induce a biolomorphism between a Riemann surface of genus $g$ and a complex $g$-torus, right? But what prevents this map to be holomorphic?

Comment: It is holomorphic, but not biholomorphic.

Comment: @Roland ok so it is 1-1, surjective, holomorphic but not biholomorphic? What is the crucial difference between this case and the genus-1 case?

Comment: It is not surjective because the source is of dimension 1 and the target of dimension $g$. That is why it is not biholomorphic.

Comment: @Roland It makes sense to me that it is not surjective, but maybe I have troubles with the statement of the Jacobi theorem, since I thought it stated the surjectivity of the Jacobi map.

Comment: Ok, so you have the map $J:X\to Jac(X)$ which is not surjective. Because $Jac(X)$ is an abelian group, the map $J$ extends by universal property to a map $Div(X)\to Jac(X)$ where $Div(X)$ is the group of divisor on $X$, that is the free abelian group on the points of $X$. This maps induces $Div(X)/\sim\to Jac(X)$ where $\sim$ is the linear equivalence. Now this last map is onto, but not the first one.

Comment: @Roland Ok, now the statement is clearer:D; if $X$ has genus one what is the difference that makes the first map $J: X \rightarrow Jac(X)$ surjective?

Comment: This is because a map of (irreducible) curves is either constant or open, and because $X$ is also proper, $J$ must be either constant or onto. Since it is constant only if $g=0$, for $g=1$, the map is onto.

Comment: @Roland Ok, now it's all very clear. Thank you very much!